# batch file for running software from a mapped drive

Tags: batch-file

Ok so I've been trying to debug this.  What happens is when it maps a drive, it doesn't map the drive to the letter I select using the net use t:.  Also it just makes more and more mapped drives every time you run it.  So if anyone can offer some insight into what's going on with this I'd appreciate it thanks!

```
@echo off
color 02
title = Start Crosslink Now
set address= \\192.168.1.147\



:start
set count=0
cls

echo                -------------Select a number -------------
echo.
echo 1) Start crosslink 2015
echo 2) Start crosslink 2014
echo 3) Start corsslink 2013
echo 4) Start crosslink 2012
echo 5) Add or Edit Crosslink paths
echo.

set /p a= Select an option:

if %a%==1 goto 15
if %a%==2 goto 14
if %a%==3 goto 13
if %a%==4 goto 12
if %a%==5 goto add
goto exit
:: This is the initial screen for Year selection.
:15

::Checks drive availability.  Reattempts connection to drive every 5         seconds.
net use t: %address%xlink15
cls
Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped *****
IF EXIST %address%xlink15 goto 15mounted
IF EXIST %address%xlink15 goto 15mounted
cls
echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again.
timeout /t 5
goto 15


:15mounted
Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2015 SOFTWARE*****

pushd t:  
start xlink32.exe
timeout /t 5
echo Going back to Main menu
timeout /t 2
exit




 :14
 ::Checks drive availability.  Reattempts connection to drive every 5 seconds.
 cls
 Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped *****
 net use t: %address%xlink14
 IF EXIST %address%xlink14 goto 14mounted
 IF EXIST %address%xlink14 goto 14mounted
 cls
 echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again.
 timeout /t 5
 goto 15


:14mounted
Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2014 SOFTWARE*****
pushd t:
start xlink32.exe
timeout /t 5

timeout /t 2
exit




:13
::Checks drive availability.  Reattempts connection to drive every 5 seconds.
net use t: %address%xlink13
cls
Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped *****
IF EXIST %address%xlink13 goto 13mounted%address%
IF EXIST %address%xlink13 goto 13mounted
cls
echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again.
timeout /t 5
goto 15


:13mounted
Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2013 SOFTWARE*****
pushd t: 
start xlink32.exe
timeout /t 5
echo Going back to Main menu
timeout /t 2
goto start



:12
::Checks drive availability.  Reattempts connection to drive every 5 seconds.
cls
Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped *****
IF EXIST %address%xlink12 goto 12mounted
net use t: %address%xlink12
IF EXIST %address%xlink12 goto 12mounted
cls
echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again.
timeout /t 5
goto 15


:12mounted
Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2012 SOFTWARE*****
pushd t: %address%xlink12
start xlink32.exe
timeout /t 5
echo Going back to Main menu
timeout /t 2
goto start







:add

cls
set /p pass=Enter Password : 
if %pass%==work1234 goto createinfo
echo incorect password going back to main menu
timeout /t 2
goto start


:createinfo
cls
Echo        ******Set Network Paths******
set /p c15=Enter crosslink 2015 network path: 
set /p c14=Enter crosslink 2014 network path: 
set /p c13=Enter crosslink 2013 network path: 
set /p c12=Enter crosslink 2012 network path: 


cls

echo         ******Set drive letters******
set /p d15=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2015: 
set /p d14=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2014: 
set /p d13=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2013: 
set /p d12=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2012: 


cls

goto create



:create

set nme=**

 echo @echo off >Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo color 02 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo title = Start Crosslink Now >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




 echo :start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo                -------------Select a number before-------------               >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 1) Start crosslink 2015 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 2) Start crosslink 2014 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 3) Start corsslink 2013 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 4) Start crosslink 2012 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 5) Add or Edit Crosslink paths >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo set /p a= Select option: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo if %a%==1 goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo if %a%==2 goto 14 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo if %a%==3 goto 13 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo if %a%==4 goto 12 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo if %a%==5 goto add >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo goto exit >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo :15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat



echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c15% goto 15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo net use %d15%: %c15% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c15% goto 15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo    :15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2015 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    pushd %d15%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat 
echo    echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




echo :14 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c14% goto 14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo net use %d14%: %c14% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c14% goto 14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


echo    :14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2014 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    pushd %d14%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




echo :13 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c13% goto 13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo net use %d13%: %c13% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c13% goto 13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo   :13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2013 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   pushd %d13% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat



 echo :12 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo IF EXIST %c12% goto 12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo net use %d12%: %c12% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo IF EXIST %c12% goto 12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


echo    :12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2012 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    pushd %d12%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo    goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat






 echo :add >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p pass=Enter Password :  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo if pass==work1234 goto createinfo >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo incorect password going back to main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo :createinfo >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo Echo        ******Set Network Paths****** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p c15=Enter crosslink 2015 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo set /p c14=Enter crosslink 2014 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo set /p c13=Enter crosslink 2013 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo set /p c12=Enter crosslink 2012 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

echo echo         ******Set drive letters****** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d15=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2015:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d14=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2014:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo set /p d13=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2013:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
echo set /p d12=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2012:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo goto create >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo :create >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 set nme=**

 echo @echo off >Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo color 02 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo title = Start Crosslink Now >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




 echo :start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo                -------------Select a number before-------------  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 1) Start crosslink 2015 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 2) Start crosslink 2014 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 3) Start corsslink 2013 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo 4) Start crosslink 2012 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo echo 5) Add or Edit Crosslink paths >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo set /p a= Select option: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo if %a%==1 goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo if %a%==2 goto 14 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo if %a%==3 goto 13 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo if %a%==4 goto 12 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo if %a%==5 goto add >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo goto exit >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo :15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat



 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo IF EXIST %c15% goto 15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo net use %d15%: %c15% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo IF EXIST %c15% goto 15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo   :15mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2015 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   pushd %d15%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat 
 echo   echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




 echo :14 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo IF EXIST %c14% goto 14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo net use %d14%: %c14% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo IF EXIST %c14% goto 14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo   :14mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2014 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   pushd %d14%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo   goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




  echo :13 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

  echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo IF EXIST %c13% goto 13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo net use %d13%: %c13% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo IF EXIST %c13% goto 13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
  echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


   echo     :13mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2013 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     pushd %d13% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
   echo     goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat



    echo :12 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

    echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo Echo *****Checking if drive is mapped ***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo IF EXIST %c12% goto 12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo net use %d12%: %c12% >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo IF EXIST %c12% goto 12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo echo The drive couldn't be found attempting again. >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo goto 15 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


    echo    :12mounted >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    Echo *****STARTING CROSSLINK 2012 SOFTWARE***** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    pushd %d12%: >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    start xlink32.exe >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    timeout /t 5 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    echo Going back to Main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
    echo    goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo :add >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p pass=Enter Password :  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo if pass==work1234 goto createinfo >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo incorect password going back to main menu >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo :createinfo >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo Echo        ******Set Network Paths****** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p c15=Enter crosslink 2015 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p c14=Enter crosslink 2014 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p c13=Enter crosslink 2013 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p c12=Enter crosslink 2012 network path:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo echo         ******Set drive letters****** >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d15=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2015:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d14=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2014:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d13=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2013:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo set /p d12=Enter Drive letter for Crosslink 2012:  >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat


 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat

 echo goto create >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat




 echo :exit >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo cls >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo echo Incorrect selection redirecting to main screen >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo timeout /t 2 >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo goto start >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat
 echo exit >>Start-Crosslink-Now-%nme%.bat









 exit


 :exit
 cls
 echo incorrect selection redirecting to main screen
 timeout /t 2
 goto start
```

Comment: Ok so I've solved the multiple mapped drives issue.  Now I just need batch window to close after it's executed the other software.

Comment: Don't tell us how you solved it or anything. People who have the same problem as you couldn't possibly want to know how you solved it. </sarcasm>

Comment: That's true, if you've solved the issue, please answer the question. If there's another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: Because it's not really the solution I wanted more of a work around.  I just put net use * /delete /yes in beginning with set address....problem is if there are mapped drives for other reasons.  Also the net use t: %address% doesn't actually name the mapped drive t:.  that's my real problem right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I fixed it.  I just moved:

```
net use t: %address%*
```

to the line below

```
::Checks drive availability.  Reattempts connection to drive every 5         seconds.
```

before

```
cls
```

Comment: Once I fixed this I can take out the "net use  * /delete" Portion all together.